# Unexpected output for looping through a string and using str.replace

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I am going through the CodingBat exercises for Java. I have got up to [this problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p171260) which asks:

> Given a string, return a version where all the `"x"` have been removed. Except an `"x"` at the very start or end should not be removed.

I wanted to solve this by checking each character from the second up to the penultimate of the string. If the character is `x`, replace it with an empty character. Here is my code:

```
public String stringX(String str) {
    String newStr = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
        if (str.indexOf('x') == i) {
            newStr += str.replace('x', '\u0000');
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

The result of this is that it doesn't seem to return any of the string passed in, if the string begins with `x`:

```
System.out.println(test.stringX("xxHxix"));
```

returns    (blank)

```
System.out.println(test.stringX("abxxxcd"));
```

returns `abcd`

```
System.out.println(test.stringX("xabxxxcdx"));
```

returns    (blank)

I really can't figure out what's going on but I want to be able to understand it before just looking at the answer.

Is it problematic to concatenate a `char` into a `string`? Should I use `substring` instead?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `string.replaceAll` function. The below regex will remove all the `x` except the ones which are at the start or at the end.

```
System.out.println("xxHxix".replaceAll("(^x|x$)|x", "$1"));
System.out.println("xabxxxcdx".replaceAll("(^x|x$)|x", "$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
xHix
xabcdx
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kX8aB7/4)

- `^x` would match the `x` which was at the start of a line. `^` anchor asserts that we are at the start.
- `x$` would match the `x` which was at the end.
- `(..)` called capturing group usually used to capture characters. So `(^x|x$)` captures the starting `x` or the `x` at the end.
- `|x` OR match all the  `x` from the remaining  string. `|` called regex alternation operator. So `(^x|x$)|x` will match all the `x` which was at the middle and captures all the `x` which was at the start or at the end.
- Replacing all the matched chars with the chars inside group index 1 will return  only the `x`'s  (which are at the start or at the end)

If you want to do a case-insensitive match then add `(?i)` modifier at the start like

```
"(?i)(^x|x$)|x"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you explain how `replaceAll` works with the `^` and `$`?

Comment: @Avinash Raj : Probably it should be case-insensitive, I am sot sure though :) But its a great solution +1

Comment: @Avinash Raj So interesting. I need to do some reading on regex!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (str.indexOf('x') == i) {
            newStr += str.replace('x', '\u0000');
        }
```

This will always return the same result, the first occurrence of `char x`. If the first occurrence of `x != i` it will never go into the if statement.

This should work:

```
public String stringX(String str) {
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            str.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

EDIT: removed the unnecessary variable declaration.

Comment: Yes `charAt` and `indexOf` provide different results.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you need `StringBuilder` for `deleteCharAt`? (PS you put it with a 't')

Comment: Yes `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`. It's one of the ways to do it. You can try to make it using `String`, `substrings` and re assignment if you don't want to use those. (PS oops typo :) )

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `newStr` and replace every `x` on it. Because `str.replace('x', '\u0000');` does so.

What you want to do is to use the method `charAt(x)` to check specific characters and create a new string with it or remove the matched indexes on the current string.

[Check out the Java Doc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)